# Enabling master mode on ath9k wireless driver

Tags: wifi

How can I enable master mode on ath9k driver, so that I can use my ubuntu machine as an wireless access point. The wireless card is: AR2427. The following command returns an error:
`sudo ip link set dev wlan0 down && sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode master`

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. Here is the tutorial I wrote: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1663788

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.